# Find location of current m-file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm working on my [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) code in a number of different locations, and it would really help if I could make the code aware of its location on the computer. I think there is a function that gives me exactly this information, but I can't remember what it is called or find it on Google.

The idea is that I have a function `myFunc` that needs a file in its own directory, which can be in different locations on different computers. So in `myFunc` I want to do something like this:

```
dir = theFunctionImLookingFor;
system(fullfile(dir, 'someApp.exe'));
```

(It could also be that the function I'm looking for doesn't return the directory, but the directory + m-file name, but that makes little difference to me.)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[mfilename](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/mfilename.html) or better `mfilename('fullpath')`

Comment: This only returns the path when running the full file.  It returns an empty string when executed from the command window or when running a single cell.

Answer (score 20):

When working with classes I often like to keep associated data in the class directory. I use [which](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/which.html) to get the path and then [fileparts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fileparts.html) to chop it up.

```
[folder, name, ext] = fileparts(which('object'));
```

Where 'object' can be a function or class name. The advantage of this method for me is that you can call it from outside the mfile in question. This is necessary if you need to get the path to a derived class from the base class for example.

Answer (score 11):

Another method, via [Walter Roberson on the MATLAB answers site](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/9907-is-there-a-function-that-retrieves-the-filename-of-the-current-script), using the [`dbstack`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dbstack.html) function:

```
S = dbstack('-completenames');
S(1).file
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [Path class](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/87552-path) you can get the file path with `Path.this` and the parent directory with `Path.here`. Use the `string` method to convert to a string if needed: `Path.this.string`.

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Comment: That’s actually quite a nice tool. But be careful about answering too many questions linking to it, lest it be seen as shameless promotion.

Comment: God forbid I solve to many problems ;)