# Matlab: Is there a way to get the path of the current script?

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find location of current m-file in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720140/find-location-of-current-m-file-in-matlab)

I have a script that is not in the current directory or on the search path.  I want to get the location of the script from the script.  Is this possible in Matlab?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`mfilename`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mfilename.html)

> #### Description
>
> mfilename returns a string
> containing the file name of the most
> recently invoked function. When called
> from within the file, it returns the
> name of that file. This allows a
> function to determine its name, even
> if the file name has been changed.
>
> p = mfilename('fullpath') returns the
> full path and name of the file in
> which the call occurs, not including
> the filename extension.
>
> c = mfilename('class') in a method,
> returns the class of the method, not
> including the leading @ sign. If
> called from a nonmethod, it yields the
> empty string.