# Do MATLAB functions know which directory they are defined in?

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find location of current m-file in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720140/find-location-of-current-m-file-in-matlab)

I would like to write an m-file that will display the directory the function is defined in.

For instance if the function foo.m is placed in the directories c:\bar and c:\foo (full path to the file is then either c:\bar\foo.m or c:\foo\foo.m), neither of which is intially on the MATLAB path, this sequence of commands

```
addpath("c:\bar");
foo
```

would produce the result: I am located in directory c:\bar

while

```
addpath("c:\foo");
foo
```

would produce the result I am located in directory c:\foo

How can I write such a function?

Comment: @gnovice I do not think it is a duplicate. The OP is asking about something on the lines of how matlab does function overloading (it uses different paths).

Comment: @Pavan: No, he's not. He's adding each function to the path *individually*, not at the same time (which *would* lead to `foo` being an overloaded function). He's specifically asking how a function can know the directory it's in, which is covered by the duplicate question.

Comment: OK I missed that entirely. Sorry.

Comment: @Marc, you can use which foo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for the [`mfilename`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mfilename.html) function? The optional `fullpath` input argument returns the full path to the m-file that the function is called from.

Answer (score 2):

Praetorian is correct. You may also be interested in the [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fileparts.html) function. Below is code that should do what you are requesting.

```
function foo
fprintf('I am located in directory %s', fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')))
```