# Matlab: How to know the name of the file are you using in the workspace?

Tags: matlab, command, workspace

sometimes I load a .m file to work in the workspace, but I usually forget what is the recent file I´ve opened. So in the same way that you write `who` and you can see the variables of the workspace I suppose there should be a command to know what is the .m file in which you are working.
Does anyone know a command like this?
Thank you so much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find location of current m-file in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720140/find-location-of-current-m-file-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2):

For newer MATLAB versions, there is a way to get the fullpath of the file currently being edited in the Editor:

```
if verLessThan('matlab', '7.10')
    %# not supported
    fname = '';
elseif verLessThan('matlab', '7.12')
    %# R2010a,R2010b: editorservices
    fname = editorservices.getActiveFilename;
else
    %# R2011a: matlab.desktop.editor API
    fname = matlab.desktop.editor.getActiveFilename;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[mfilename](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/mfilename.html) seemed to be the right choice, but it returns an empty string when called from the command line. Therefore you may check the 'command history' provided by the IDE.

For larger projects it most often makes sense to use MATLAB's object model or at least functions in order to structure your work. Working in the 'workspace' often results in unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this to bootstrap runs:

```
%%
params.run = 'hairy.m';
params.hair = 10;

setup_defaults(params);

run_lots_of_code(params);
```

This has advantages as it hides the 'globals' in a single global (params), and the global tells you where they came from.