# Matlab Command Window Output Source

Tags: matlab, command-prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find location of current m-file in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720140/find-location-of-current-m-file-in-matlab)

does anyone knows how to find which function is providing output to the command window in Maltab? I've written a code with many functions, I have output to the command window but I can't find which function is responsible for that. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If all output is printed by your own code, you can easily replace all `fprintf` and `disp` calls with your own function calls that optionally prefix all output with the function name.

Here's the code:

getfunctionname.m:

```
function [CurrentFunctionName, PreviousFunctionName] = getfunctionname()
CurrentFunctionName = '';
PreviousFunctionName = '';
MyStack = dbstack('-completenames');
if (length(MyStack) < 2)
    error('Function getfunctionname.m cannot be called from MATLAB console.');
elseif (length(MyStack) == 2)
    CurrentFunctionName = MyStack(2).name;
else
    CurrentFunctionName = MyStack(2).name;
    PreviousFunctionName = MyStack(3).name;
end
return
```

myprintf.m:

```
function myprintf(varargin)
global PrefixOutputWithFunctionName
if (PrefixOutputWithFunctionName)
    [~, PreviousFunctionName] = getfunctionname;
    fprintf('### %s.m:\n', PreviousFunctionName);
end
disp(sprintf(varargin{:}));
return
```

mydisp.m:

```
function mydisp(varargin)
global PrefixOutputWithFunctionName
if (PrefixOutputWithFunctionName)
    [~, PreviousFunctionName] = getfunctionname;
    fprintf('### %s.m:\n', PreviousFunctionName);
end
disp(varargin{:});
return
```

mainfunction.m:

```
function mainfunction()
global PrefixOutputWithFunctionName

% set PrefixOutputWithFunctionName to false to disable prefixing.
PrefixOutputWithFunctionName = true;

% the code goes here...

% example output.
myprintf('some text...\n some more text...');
return
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I couldn't get it... I tried but I get the following error:

??? Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)
to change the limit.  Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can
crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

Error in ==> getfunctionname

Comment: Well, `getfunctionname` uses `dbstack` to get the name of the function that called `getfunctionname` function and returns it. Actually you could also use `mfilename` for that, but to get the name of previous function you need to used `dbstack` anyway. `myprintf` checks the value of global variable `PrefixOutputWithFunctionName`, if it's true then it prefixes the `fprintf` output with the name of the function that called it. `mainfunction.m` is just a simple example how you could define the global variable `PrefixOutputWithFunctionName` and use `myprintf`. `mydisp` is similar but for `disp`.

Comment: `getfunctionname` runs nicely for me by running `mainfunction` example code. I think you are using it in a different configuration (maybe inside a recursive function?) and somehow then you run out of stack or reach the recursion limit, maybe `dbstack` has something to do with it, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks again nrz, I'm not sure whats going on. It also works for me with mainfunction but when I use it inside the full code it reaches the recursion limit. I'll watch it again and let you know !