# Matlab find position of Command Window output

Tags: matlab

I took a look at a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890106/matlab-command-window-output-source) , but the answer as well as the linked question within didn't match my exact problem.

Assume, that I have several Matlab files that are executed by a program. During the execution of the code, I receive multiple outputs in the command window, which I want to get rid of. Of course, I could just `grep` all `disp` and `printf` commands, no problem. However, there is also the possibility, that certain computations print something without Matlab giving me a warning for a missing semicolon. An example would be

```
function dummy1
norm(1)
end
```

Which would print `1` to the command window, but Matlab does not give me a warning for a missing semicolon as it would be the case for

```
function dummy2
1+1
end
```

Is there a way to detect the position of the command that prints to command window?

Comment: This might be one of the few cases where I would use [`evalc`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) to suppress all output to the command line in the first place. This way you can call your main function like `evalc('main.m');`. Note that `diary`, `more` and `input` are disabled when using `evalc`. This does not answer your question but solves your initial *problem*.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to over-complicate it. Just place some breakpoints in your code and step through until you find those lines that produce unwanted output. Then suppress the output with `;`. The best practice is to never omit `;`. If you want to display something quickly, use commands like `disp` instead.

Furthermore, you should get used to logging everything through a proper logger, like e.g. [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/). That gives you fine-grained control over what you actually log and where via a simple config (and can also be changed programmatically). If you had used it, it would not be a problem for you to find out which log message is printed where because you'd see the component name that printed it.