# Find location of current mlapp-file (app designer) in MATLAB R2016a

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, matlab-app-designer

I'm using `pwd` function to generate current path in app designer of MATLAB R2016a but this function finds MATLAB current folder (main window of MATLAB) not app designer current folder. What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  MATLAB doesn't have multiple current directories.

Comment: @excaza. When we use `pwd` in app designer, this function finds MATLAB current folder in main window not the path that the designed app is running there (we don't have this problem in `GUIDE`). When we run an app in `GUIDE`, this app changes the current folder of MATLAB to `GUIDE` app, so `pwd` function finds the app path (same as current folder of MATLAB in this situation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find location of current m-file in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720140/find-location-of-current-m-file-in-matlab)

Comment: @excaza. Thank you. Please add your answer. + we need to remove file name in the end of path.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for the answer of your question. In the comments of your question the hardest part of the problem was given by "excaza". But I eventually used:

```
[directory,~,~] = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));
```

Good luck

Comment: This works only once. Close the app and open again OR call the method twice, it will give MATLAB working directory.